# how to model routing to add one to many relationship in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am kind of stuck to model a simple relationship.

So a member has none or many address details.

Member object has none to many relationship to object AddressDetail.

So once a member is created then the member can add AddressDetails to itself.

In terms of the URL routing, whether I should see this as:
Member/1/AddressDetail/Add

or it should be totally independent from the member and the route should be

/AddressDetail/Add

then pass the logged in user id while the address is created?

similarly you can think of this as each user is a part of an organisation and each organisation might have zero to many address details.

How the routing should be done? with sub controllers or it should be at the main controller level for each entity?

Comment: If you need the flexibility for a user to create `AddressDetails` for other than themselves it could be `/AddressDetail/Create/1` (where the 3rd value is the ID of the `Member` )

Comment: the only way that another user would be able to create an address detail for another user is the admin users. Or an admin should be able to add new address details for each organisations. so in those circumstances how the routing should be done?

Comment: Then the method in the controller could be `Create(int? ID)`. If the user is an admin, pass the ID of the member, (the url would be `/Address/Create/1`) other wise ignore the parameter (or throw an exception) so that a non-admin user can only create an address for themselves (the url would be just `/Address/Create`)